# Change login_message using title

Tags: login

I'm trying to add message on the login forms. How do I change the contents according to the page title or url parameters

this code goes to my functions.php

```
function custom_login_message() {
  $message = "<h2>". PAGE TITLE HERE ."</h2>";
  return $message;
}
add_filter('login_message', 'custom_login_message');
```

I want it to change for the pages login, register and lost password.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the login page, then the best place to start is looking here on the Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form

(The codex is the best place to start for a lot of things...)

You will find lots of info and examples on how to customize various parts of the login form and text.